# How to displaying a dictionary key based on value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a lists:

```
dct = {'A': a1, 'B': b2}

a1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
b2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

On the basis of which the list is drawn up:

```
c = [2, 8, 5]
```

And how do you go back to the dictionary keys? For the `c` list to display as:

```
c2 = [AAB]
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: What if a number from `c` is contained in both `a1` and `b2`?  What a number from `c` is in neither `a1` nor `b2`?

Comment: @wim The values in `a1` and `b2` are always different.

Comment: There are ways to do this, but this is probably not the right use case for a dict- the purpose of a dict is to do constant time lookups based on a key. It would probably make a lot more sense to create a dict as {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A'} to allow you to map directly from a list of integers to a list of letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build an additional mapping from values in the lists to the keys of the dictionary, then use that to lookup the keys for values in the list `c`:

```
>>> a1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> b2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> dct = {'A': a1, 'B': b2}
>>> d = {x: k for k, v in dct.items() for x in v}    
>>> d
{0: 'A', 2: 'A', 4: 'A', 6: 'A', 8: 'A', 1: 'B', 3: 'B', 5: 'B', 7: 'B', 9: 'B'}
>>> c = [2, 8, 5]
>>> "".join(d[x] for x in c)
'AAB'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Iterative* approach:

```
a1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
b2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
dct = {'A': a1, 'B': b2}
c = [2, 8, 5]
result = ''

for i in c:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if i in v:
            result += k
            break

print(result)   # AAB
```

Comment: nice solution :)

Comment: The time complexity of this solution is quadratic: for each item in `c` you need to scan all values' lists..

Answer (score 0):

object/dict
has a method called .viewkeys()

try
dct = {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b2'}
print(dct.viewkeys())

Comment: No problem learning python myself right now lmao glad to help out :)

Comment: There's no `dict.viewkeys()` in Python 3.

Comment: dct = {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b2'} 
print(dct.keys())

try list(dct.keys())